# Error al pasar una variable con una cadena a una funcion con onclick

Tags: javascript

estoy utilizando onclick en un boton pasandole una variable la cual contiene una cadena.

```
"<button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Detalles' onclick='funcion("+cadena+");'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i></button>"
```

este boton lo agrego a una columna de una tabla mediante otra funcion la cual pinta toda la informacion de la tabla como se muestra a continuacion.

```
    function pintarTabla(){
     var fila = document.createElement('tr');
     fila.innerHTML += ("<td>"valor"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+valor+"...</td>"
                    + "<td>"valor"</td>"
                    + "<td>"valor"</td>"
                    + "<td class=text-center><button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Detalles' onclick='funcion("+cadena+");'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i></button></td>"
                );
                document.getElementById('tabla').appendChild(fila);
     }
```

La variable cadena contiene como su nombre lo dice una cadena como esta "PEDRO AGUILAR GOMEZ", entonces dentro ya pintado queda lo siquiente:

```
"<button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Detalles' onclick='mostrarDetalles(PEDRO AGUILAR GOMEZ);'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i></button>"
```

Hasta aqui todo va bien pero cuando hago click en el boton obtengo este error **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Lei al respecto y al parecer se refiere a que no entiende cuando termina el string.
aun no he econtrado la forma de como pasarle el valor utilizando la logica del principio (pintar la tabla). como dato adicional en otra funcion similar paso como parametro un numero entero y no obtengo ningun problema. Espero pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tienes que encerrar el dato entre comillas para que la función lo interprete como texto, prueba con

```
"<td class=text-center><button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Detalles' onclick='funcion(\""+cadena+"\");'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i></button></td>"
```

la salida resultante debe ser:

```
<button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Detalles' onclick='mostrarDetalles("PEDRO AGUILAR GOMEZ");'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i></button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.